# Simplifying Boolean Expression

Tags: logical-operators, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have a function `f(a,b,c,d) = b*(a+~c) + d*(a+~b)`, where `*(AND)`, `+(OR)`, `~(NOT)`.

Using the distributive law, I get: `ba + b~c + da + d~b`,

but the answer is `ab + b~c + d~b`.

I can't figure out, how to get rid of the `da`.

I tried factoring out an a to get: `a(b+d) + b~c + d~b`, but that doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It may be more suitable for a different [se] site such as [math.se] instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean logic instead of programming or coding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean logic, not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table with all the possible values for each parameter: [1,0] and calculate both expressions. If you can show that in each and every case they evaluate to the same result, you'll show that they're equivalent and thus the `ad` can be dropped.

I'll demonstrate and let you complete the exercise:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So the question is why **`ba + b~c + da + d~b = ab + b~c + d~b`**.

The reason is simple, **`da` adds nothing to the left side**.

If it would, there would be a case where **`da = true`** and **`ab + b~c + d~b = false`**. However, if **`da = true`**, then **`d = true`** and **`a = true`**. If **`b`** is also **`true`**, then **`ab = true`** and we have added nothing to the right side. If **`b = false`**, then **`d~b = true`** and we haven't added anything either.

It is ok to use tables or transformation rules such as distribution, etc. However, it is always better try to understand why two expressions are equivalent.